changes to serial driver name with kernel 6.8 and later
prior to kernel 6.8 [edit: actually prior to and including 6.3; i am not in a position to check kernels inbetween 6.3 and 6.8], the driver path for fixed serial ports (ttySxx) resolved to /sys/bus/platform/drivers/serial8250 and simply checking that the name was "serial8250" sufficed to decide between a fixed and a removable (USB) device - if the driver name was NOT "serial8250" then one could assume that it was (a) a removable device and (b) no further checking was required to assure it was a real device (ie, not just a placeholder).
this was used in the solution to checking ports offered by Soren Holm here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530096/how-to-find-all-serial-devices-ttys-ttyusb-on-linux-without-opening-them
i have been using a Pascal translation of Soren's code for a number of years in software i have written without any problems or complaints.
but from kernel 6.8 onwards (Ubuntu 24.04LTS), the driver path has changed. now it resolves to /sys/bus/serial-base/drivers/port, and the name "port" is a tad too generic to use as a basis for making decisions - kernel 6.8 breaks Soren's code. so far, i have been unable to find any useful discussion online about this change in the kernel.
my question is, with kernel 6.8 and later, is there any reliable alternative check to determine if a serial port is associated with what was the "serial8250" driver? are there any experts out there who know about the serial port driver changes, why they were made, and workarounds for the consequences?
cheers,
rob   :-)
addendum: clarified that i have checked 6.3 and prior kernels, 6.8 and later kernels, but NOT kernels inbetween 6.3 and 6.8. so changes could have been made anywhere after kernel 6.3

You mention a kernel that is used by various Ubuntu product & more than single release. If you have problems with your unstated Ubuntu product with the 6.8 kernel, and you're using the HWE kernel stack (you don't provide release details), you can switch to the GA kernel stack & thus not use 6.8 anymore. Options available vary on product & release, and you've not given that basic starting point (LTS releases have kernel stack choice don't forget; the install media only sets the default stack)

i'm running Linux Mint XFCE 22, which is based upon Ubuntu 24.04LTS. in this distribution (Mint 22) there is no option to use a pre-6.8 kernel. i write software that is used by other folks, so will be running on a variety of different systems. what i;ve encountered is the result of a change upstream from Mint, and quite likely upstream from Ubuntu. i'm just hoping that someone here can offer some additional information.

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)

guiverc - while i respect your opinion, the O/S i am running is based on Ubuntu 24.04LTS and the results i am seeing reside entirely within the Ubuntu code-base. can we just pretend that i am running Ubuntu 24.04LTS, as the topic of discussion is common to both Ubuntu and Mint? if you really wish to push the point, i can create an Ubuntu 24.04LTS install on a spare SSD and thereby provide evidence that it generates the same results as Mint 22.
